# Call a .net dll from VB

Tags: c#, com

whether .net framework required to run a .tlb file generated from c#?

Comment: If this is VB 6 or VBScript, I believe you will have to create a Runtime Callable Wrapper for your C# classes.

Comment: I have generated the tlb file from c# class library.same tlb is used in my vb project. It work in my development pc not in test.
Do I need .net framework to use tlb in vb 6.0?

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

- make sure the classes that you want to use in your VB app are ComVisible
- make sure the classes that you want to use in your VB app have a Guid assigned to it
- it is best practice to create an interface for those classes
- create a tlb file from the assembly using regasm
- The .NET framework (runtime) needs to be installed.  It is not that regasm will 'compile' your assembly into another language or something that does not need the .NET runtime.  A runtime callable wrapper is created, so that you can invoke the .NET assembly as from VB6, which means the .NET runtime is still required.

Comment: For my production ,I cannot force to install the .net framework.
My requirement is to call a webservice from vb 6.0.I created a com intreop for the proxy class,this works fine if I have .net framework on all the client machine. The other way is to use soap toolkit 3.0,but it is not supported in vista,How do I make a make a generic solution?

Answer (score 0):

In VB.Net you can use it normally. In previous version use Runtime Callable Wrapper. More information is here in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817248).